# getting storage information in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-hardware

I was wondering how I can get the information about any memory card, internal storage that an android device have! what I want is the free, used memory amount and if possible the extra details about memory card! ( not the internal Storage )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941552/android-sd-card-free-space

Comment: refer this to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133417/android-get-free-size-of-internal-external-memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you to get free memory of external storage:

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getAvailableBlocks();
long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);
Log.d("","Available MB : "+megAvailable);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: You can also read-http://saga-androidapplication.blogspot.in/2011/09/phone-internal-and-external-storage.html

Comment: I have posted the above code as i have done it before.and you can compare the code its not the pretty same.

Comment: as if already correct answer is given by some one, is it required to repeat the same.

Comment: that was not my intension,i also posted the link through which i implemented the same think a couple of weeks before.