# How to Find Internal and External storage of a device programmatically in android

Tags: android

I want to find the information regarding internal and external storage capacity of a device programmatically in android . Any Ideas ?

Comment: refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5083482/2345913)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the environment variable. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` . There many methods in `Environment.java` . It depends on what information you need . For example to get external storage name you use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName();`
there are other methods you can make use of them.  For Internal storage the api's may not be available publicly .

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(type.getPath());
long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize()*(long)stat.getAvailableBlocks();  
long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);  
Log.i("TAG","Available size in MB : "+megAvailable);
```

Now we can use `getAvailableBytes()` api instead of using `getBlockSize` which is deprecated in API level 18.

where `type` is `File` object which might be of type `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`